# MassTransit In memory setup for two different application running on same process

Tags: masstransit

I have two different applications which are running on the same process by creating AppDomain for each of the two applications. The bus setup for application1 looks like this :

```
  builder.Register(c =>
            {
                var inMemoryTransportCache = new InMemoryTransportCache(Environment.ProcessorCount);
                var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingInMemory( sbc =>
                {
                    sbc.SetTransportProvider(inMemoryTransportCache);
                });
                return bus.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri(busDestination)).Result;
            }).As<ISendEndpoint>();
```

The bus setup for application2 looks like this :

```
builder.Register(c =>
            {
                var inMemoryTransportCache = new InMemoryTransportCache(Environment.ProcessorCount);
                var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingInMemory(sbc =>
                {
                    sbc.ReceiveEndpoint("TestQueue", ce =>
                    {
                        ce.LoadFrom(c);
                    });
                    sbc.SetTransportProvider(inMemoryTransportCache);
                });

                return bus;
            })
                .As<IBusControl>()
                .As<IBus>()
                .SingleInstance();

            builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<IBusControl>().GetSendEndpoint(
                new Uri("destinationUrl")).Result)
                .As<ISendEndpoint>()
                .SingleInstance();
```

When i send a message from application 1 to application 2 , application 2 does not receive it.

From the masstransit documentation it looks like other than the receive end point we don't have to specify anything else when running in memory .

Am i doing something wrong in the setup? i.e does the destination url matter when running in-memory.
Do i have to specify the consumers as well in application2?

Any help would be much appreciated.(Using masstransit version 3.4.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate AppDomains have separate memory space, and thus are unable to share the same transport. Thus, you can't use the InMemoryTransport for inter-AppDomain communication. Believe me, it would be awesome if you could, but you can't.

Why are you using two separate AppDomains anyway? If you can collapse it into a single domain, it will work as expected.

Comment: We are trying to implement running of acceptance tests in memory. So our acceptance test project which uses spec flow initialises different app domains for each of the applications i.e. api console host, application console host , so that different applications can run on the same process and hence utilise the in-memory bus just for the sake of end to end testing.